# How to send back a a HTTP 200 code webhooks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webhooks

I try to send back a `HTTP code 200` to my webhooks, so I have two questions :

Is the following code in my controller is enough to send back the 200 code :

```
def webhooks
   head 200
end
```

And how do I display the response of my webhooks ? 
I tried to do a `response.body` but nothing displayed
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
  render json: {}.to_json, status: 200
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I also asked my customer service, i was told that I can't use webhooks with my localhost. So I will make a try to create a mock server with postman !